# Replace frontpage and menues with a module

Tags: angularjs, drupal

Im using drupal (quite new at it as well). 
I've made a module thats written in angular, it list some ads and articles from a json. 
If I go to localhost/drupalTest/ads I'll see all ads with my format. 
Now I want to replace frontpage and all its menues with my module.

Is this possible or is there another way to do this?

Br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto

> admin/config/system/site-information

and change the **Default front page** to your newly created menu, from your example,

> drupalTest/ads